# hiding php extension with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

This is the code I use to hide php extension

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

It works perfect but I am getting one problem.

when I want to access blog.php, I simply create link as http://example.com/blog and it works.

I also have file as blog-post.php in same folder so I create link as http://example.com/blog-post.

But It gets redirected to http://example.com/blog with 302 header (I found this in developer tools, on webpage it doesn't shows any error.)

Also I want to make this blog-post search engine friendly like http://example.com/blog/id-of-blog/title-of-blog

So please do tell me how make this possible?

Comment: no it is not wordpress, it is direct php with .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible,

try this code with your .htacccess file,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: just check it again I change the rule.

Comment: I tried this new rule but Only index page working but other links still not working

Comment: remove all your previous and try with this only.

Comment: I have tried this before already, this is the same code I used to use before creating blog-post, it works but it has problem which I have mentioned in question.

Answer (score 0):

why are you all using same method. This is alternate method for hide extension. 
Your file must be like this: 
 `<a href='aboutus'>about us</a>` 
instead of 
`<a href="aboutus.php">about us </a>` 
Now you add this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d <br>
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f <br>
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-l<br>
RewriteCond ^aboutus aboutus.php [L]<br>
```